# Implementing sigmoid function in python

Tags: python, activation-function, sigmoid

I am trying to implement a simple neural network for XOR function.
The activation function I am using is Sigmoid function.
The code for the sigmoid function is:

```
def ActivationFunction(a)
    e = 2.671                   # Sigmoid Function
    expo = e ** a
    val = expo / (1 + expo)
    return val
```

My problem is that this function is always returning a value between 0.7 and 0.8. This problem is showing a major effect in the output process.

Any suggestions would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is implemented correctly, however, the value of `e` is incorrect.

I'd recommend importing `math` and using the predefined `e` constant from there.

```
import math    
def sigmoid(x):
     return 1 / (1 + math.e ** -x)  # mathematically equivalent, but simpler
```

And, accordingly, the derivative:

```
def sigmoid_derivative(a):
    return a * (1 - a)
```

Where `a` is the hidden activation from the forward pass.

Besides this, I see nothing wrong with your implementation. So if you're *still* getting values you don't expect after the fix, the cause of the trouble lies elsewhere.

Comment: Changing the value is not making much of a difference, the output is still somewhere between 0.7 and 0.8

Comment: @PiyushRaut Well, it would depend on what you're passing to the function, right?

Comment: According to my network, roughly I am passing values ranging from 0.7 to 1.5

Comment: @PiyushRaut In that case, it's not the function's fault that everything comes out to be between 0.7 and 0.8, don't you think?

Comment: Yes I am working on that. I am currently new to neural networks

Comment: It is common to "normalize" your input to a neural network when using a sigmoid activation function.  Every column of input data is adjusted so that it has a mean of zero and a standard deviation of 1.